# Is there a guide on learning iPhone development from the perspective of an Android developer?

Tags: iphone, android

I consider myself an Android developer, after having created four apps and learned a lot by creating them. Now I've begun my venture into the iPhone app development world, and I don't remember the Android learning curve being this extreme. It doesn't help, though, that I was very familiar with Java and Eclipse whereas I hardly even know how to use OS X.

I learn fast and I know exactly what I want to make, I just need the means to get there. I'm really floundering with Xcode and the new project templates (of which there are several, and I hardly know what they mean). I know there are many books and things out there for starting from scratch but I feel like my Android knowledge should count for something.

**Is there a good resource for learning the basics of iPhone development, given that I am quite familiar with the Android platform?** I'm looking for anything that converts Android knowledge to iPhone knowledge; a table of UI element names in each platform, or of concept equivalents, or a compare/contrast of the frameworks involved, or anything that will increase the rate of learning given that I know the Android platform already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't *exactly* what you're looking for, but here's a guide for learning Objective C for Java developers.  [Objective-C for Java Programmers, Part 1](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1568732)

That's the best I could find searching; seems like a niche could be filled if someone wrote up some good comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a guide that's meant to compare C++ to Objective-C concepts, but also has a fair amount of Java sprinkled throughout:

http://pierre.chachatelier.fr/programmation/fichiers/cpp-objc-en.pdf

I think it's way more comprehensive than the other link posted, also more straightforward.

However I think you were really looking more for mappings of UI concepts.  There I am not sure of a good resource... I think your best bet is to read through the iOS overview:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html

And read through the frameworks to try and get a broad overview of what is there.  Apple actually has truly excellent and extensive online documentation, not just of classes but of concepts and frameworks.